# Does an algorithm exist to identify different queries/questions in sentence?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-mining

I want to identifies different queries in sentences.

Like - `Who is Bill Gates and where he was born?` or `Who is Bill Gates, where he was born?` contains two queries

1. Who is Bill Gates?
2. Where Bill Gates was born

I worked on Coreference resolution, so I can identify that `he` points to `Bill Gates` so resolved sentence is "Who is Bill Gates, where Bill Gates was born"

Like wise

```
MGandhi is good guys, Where he was born?
single query
who is MGandhi and where was he born?
2 queries
who is MGandhi, where he was born and died?
3 queries
India won world cup against Australia, when?
1 query (when India won WC against Auz)
```

I can perform Coreference resolution but not getting how can I distinguish queries in it. 
How to do this?

I checked various sentence parser, but as this is pure nlp stuff, sentence parser does not identify it.

I tried to find "Sentence disambiguation" like "word sense disambiguation", but nothing exist like that.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciable.

Comment: Unlike your examples, multiple queries can be somewhat implicit. How many queries would you consider to be present in this question: `Where was the bag stolen and recovered from?`

Comment: Yeah, I am looking to write generic rule for some selected patterns. That might help

Answer (score 2):

Natural language is full of exceptions. Especially in English, it is often said that there are more exceptions than rules. So, it is almost impossible to get a completely accurate solution that works *every single time*, but using a parser, you can achieve reasonably good performance.

I like to use the [Berkeley parser](https://code.google.com/p/berkeleyparser/%20%22Berkeley%20Parser) for such tasks. Their [online demo](http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html) includes a graphical representation of the parse tree, which is extremely helpful when trying to formulate heuristics.

For example, consider the question "*Who is Bill Gates and where was he born?*". The parse tree looks like this:

[image: parse-tree]

Clearly, you can split the tree at the central conjunction (`CC`) node to extract the individual queries. In general, this will be easy if the parsed sentence is simple (where there will be only one query) or compound (where the individual queries can be split by looking at conjunction nodes, as above).

Another more complex example in your question has three queries, such as "*Who is Gandhi and where did he work and live?*". The parse tree:

[image: parse-tree]

Again, you can see the conjunction node which splits "*Who is Gandhi*" and "Where did he work and live*". The parse does not, however, split up the second query into two, as you would ideally want. And that brings us to the hardest part of what you are trying to do: dealing with (computationally, of course) what is known as [right node raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising). This is a linguistic construct where common parts get *shared*.

For example, consider the question "*When and how did he suffer a setback?*". What it really asks is (a) when did he suffer a setback?, and (b) how did he suffer a setback? Right-node raising issues cannot be solved by just parse trees. It is, in fact, one of the harder problems in computational linguistics, and belongs to the domain of hardcore academic research.